# GestureRecognizers stop working after using presentModalViewController and dismissing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I am initializing my gesture recognizers with the following code when I initialize a view.  However, after multiple times of presenting a view on top of the one with the gesture recognizers and dismissing it with presentModalViewController and dismissModelViewController, the gesture recognizers stop working on the original view.  I've tried manually releasing the recognizers in the view's dealloc function rather than using autorelease, but it doesn't seem to help.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Also, I should mention that this problem only happens on the device, and not the simulator.

```
-(void) initializeGestures {    

recognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)] autorelease];
//recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
[(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
recognizer.delegate = self;

swipeLeftGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureLeft:)] autorelease];
//swipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureLeft:)];
swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
swipeLeftGesture.delegate = self;

swipeRightGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureRight:)] autorelease];
//swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureRight:)];
swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; // default
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
swipeRightGesture.delegate = self;
}

-(IBAction) handleSwipeGestureLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    [self swipeLeft];
}

-(IBAction) handleSwipeGestureRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    [self swipeRight];
}

-(IBAction) handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    [self gotoDefinition];
}
```

Comment: You should be releasing the gesture recognizers in the `-initializeRecognizers` method and not in the `-dealloc`. Are you releasing/autoreleasing the gesture recognizers elsewhere too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did the view with gesture recognizers dealloc when you present another viewController?
this will cause the view remove gesture recognizers on it

Comment: nope, I don't deallocate the one with the gesture recognizers.  Also, I should mention that this problem only happens on the device, and not the simulator.

Comment: can you show me functions that do the presentModalViewController and dismissViewController jobs?